# Importing Appcelerator Windows Phone project in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, profiling, appcelerator

I am creating a windows phone application in appcelerator. Is there a way I can profile my appcelerator windows project in Visual Studio 2015?
I would want to see memory usage of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to import Appcelerator project into Visual Studio.
However, Appcelerator also offers Profiler to see memory and performance data of your application.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Code_Profiler

I know it works for iOS and Android, but not sure about Windows apps. Maybe you can give a try.